# Olark free alternatives

Tags: asp.net-mvc, instant-messaging

I am looking for something similar to Olark. Such as reall time chat on a website with customers where you can use an IM client. I would also like it to be white label. Does anyone know of any free alternatives or a library you can drop into a project?

Answer (score 4):

Take a look to [SignalR](https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR) framework which exactly allows what you want.

Here's an [article](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/AsynchronousScalableWebApplicationsWithRealtimePersistentLongrunningConnectionsWithSignalR.aspx) from Scott Hanselman who has made a chat in 12 lines of code and [another one](http://blog.maartenballiauw.be/post/2011/11/29/Techniques-for-real-time-client-server-communication.aspx) with more details about the technology.

Finally, a [sample chat application](http://jabbr.net/).

Comment: This is open source, it has a [MIT license](https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/blob/master/LICENSE.md). See this [link](http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php) for details about MIT.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you build an alternative with framework likes :

http://www.ape-project.org/

a demo can be found here :

http://www.ape-project.org/demos/1/ape-real-time-chat.html

Or by using the Html 5 websockets ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure it's what you want, but tale a look on : https://www.frozenmountain.com/websync/